# Loop through an array using each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="background_cycler">
    <img class="active" src="" alt=""/>
    <img src="" alt=""   />
    <img src="" alt=""  />
    <img src="" alt=""/>        
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var bgImg = [
'img/bg1.jpg',
'img/bg2.jpg',
'img/bg3.jpg',
'img/bg4.jpg'
];

$("#background_cycler").each(function(index){
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", bgImg[index]);
});
```

The above code inserted `bg1.jpg` into all of my images, where is my mistake? I thought I loop through the `bgImg` array using `each()`'s index?

Comment: because you are selecting with id...selector will return first matched element with given id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate all images inside `background_cycler` div like

```
$("#background_cycler img").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("src", bgImg[index]);
});
```

You are using `background_cycler` id as selector so it is find first image from div but you need all images inside `background_cycler` div so you need to loop using `$("#background_cycler img").each` as described above.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked accordingly by @Elton Jamie.